# Javascript drop menu not working in Dart template

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dart

So I had a javascript drop-down menu which worked but when I place the menu HTML into a Dart component template then the menu no longer works. I guess this is due to the Javascript not being able to access those DOM elements anymore.

Is this a common problem that people have? Is there any workaround?

My global javascript was:

```
$('body')
.on('mouseenter', '.navbar.main [data-toggle="dropdown"]', function()
{ 
      if (!$(this).parent('.dropdown').is('.open'))
        $(this).click();
});

else {
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').dropdown();
}

$('.navbar.main')
  .on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown.open').find('> [data-toggle="dropdown"]').click();
  });
```

---

So, in the end I re-write this Javascript in Dart in the component as:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'dart:html' show querySelector;
import 'dart:html';

@Component(
    applyAuthorStyles:true,
    publishAs: 'cmp',
    selector: 'menu',
    templateUrl: '../lib/components/menu.html')

class MenuComponent extends AttachAware with ShadowRootAware {

  MenuComponent(Scope scope) {
  }

  void attach() {
  }

  void closeAllOpenMenus(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').classes.remove("open");    
  }

  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle').onMouseEnter.listen((event) {
      closeAllOpenMenus(shadowRoot);

      Element element = event.target.parent;
      element.classes.add("open");
    });    
    shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.navbar').onMouseLeave.listen((event) {
      closeAllOpenMenus(shadowRoot);
    });    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with shadowDOM.

As far as I know jQuery still doesn't support shadowDOM.

```javascript
.on('mouseenter', '.navbar.main [data-toggle="dropdown"]', function()
```

This code won't find elements with attribute `data-toggle="dropdown"` inside components and thus the drowdown functionality is not applied.

This also applies to CSS where Bootstraps selectors won't find elements inside components. A workaround is to add or link the CSS inside the component.
This doesn't solve situations where the ancestor of a selector (`.ancestor .descendant { color: #fff; }` is outside a component and the descendant inside a component because such selectors don't cross shadow DOM boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a delegate on a "fixed" (read: not templated) parent selector.
Assuming the event can be bound to that parent and the template can be loaded inside the parent. This way you can add items dynamically and the delegate will still find the inner elements. Found a nice article [right here](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).